# html sanitization makes difficulties

Tags: php, html, security, xss, html-injections

I read user profiles from database and show them. Before I show them I use HTML sanitizing through php htmlentities. It shows them correctly. But, while allowing user to edit it, it is shown like double filtered.

```
echo '<input id="about" name="about" value="'.$php_filtered_value>.'">';
```

Then inside the input, ampersand would look like `&amp;`
If I don't filter the variable there is worry about html injection.

What should I do?

Comment: Don't filter input fields. Only when showing them on the profile page.

Comment: You may use [`htmlentitydecode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to follow OWASP RULE#2:

```
>  RULE #2 - Attribute Escape Before Inserting Untrusted Data into HTML
Requirements:
-Aggressive HTML Entity Encoding
-Only place untrusted data into a whitelist of safe attributes (listed below).
-Strictly validate unsafe attributes such as background, id and name.
```

Please see [XSS (Cross Site Scripting) Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.232_-_Attribute_Escape_Before_Inserting_Untrusted_Data_into_HTML_Common_Attributes)

Answer (score 0):

Don't double escape the text then (as in: once before storing it in the database and again before echoing it).

- Unescaped (what you typed): `Able & Baker`
- Escaped once (what is being stored in the DB): `Able &amp; Baker`
- **Double-escaped** (what is ending up in your HTML): `Able &amp;amp; Baker`

Rather, escape the text only once: generally on the output side, not on the input side.